# Existence of a Lyapunov function for a log-concave measure

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, stochastic-differential-equations, probability-distributions

Let $d\in\mathbb N$, $f:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R$ be convex with $$\int e^{-f(x)}\:{\rm d}x<\infty\tag1$$ and $\mu$ denote the measure with density $e^{-f}$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)$. Moreover, let $$\Gamma(\varphi,\psi):=\langle\nabla\varphi,\nabla\psi\rangle\;\;\;\text{for }\varphi,\psi\in\mathcal A_0:=C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$$ and $$A\varphi:=\Delta\varphi-\langle\nabla f,\nabla\varphi\rangle\;\;\;\text{for }\varphi,\psi\in\mathcal A_0.$$

> I want to show that we can find the following objects:
>
> 1. $K\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)$ with $\mu(K)\in(0,\infty)$
> 2. $L\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)$ with $L\supseteq K$ and $$\int_K\left|\varphi-m_K(\varphi)\right|^2\:{\rm d}\mu\le C_{K,\:L}\int_L\Gamma(\varphi)\:{\rm d}\mu\tag2\;\;\;\text{for all }\varphi\in\mathcal A_0,$$ where $$m_K(\varphi):=\frac1{\mu(K)}\int_K\varphi\:{\rm d}\mu$$ and $\Gamma(\varphi):=\Gamma(\varphi,\varphi)$
> 3. $J:\mathbb R^d\to[1,\infty)$ with $J\in\mathcal A:=C^\infty(\mathbb R^d)$ and $$1\le-\frac{AJ}{\lambda J}+b1_K\tag3$$ for some $\lambda,b>0$

My idea is as follows: Let $c,R>0$ and $J:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R$ with $$J(x)=e^{c|x|}\;\;\;\text{for all }|x|\ge R\tag4$$ and $$J(x)\ge1\;\;\;\text{for all }|x|\le R\tag5.$$ Note that $$(LJ)(x)=\left(c+\frac{d-1}{|x|}\right)cJ(x)-\frac{cJ(x)}{|x|}\langle\nabla f(x),x\rangle\tag6$$ for all $|x|>R$ and hence $$1\le-\frac{(LJ)(x)}{\lambda|x|}\Leftrightarrow\frac\lambda c+c+\frac{d-1}{|x|}\le\frac{\langle\nabla f(x),x\rangle}{|x|}\tag7$$ for all $|x|>R$. Now, we somehow need to use that [by convexity of $f$ and $(1)$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/321797/91890) $$\lim_{r\to\infty}\inf_{|x|\:\ge\:r}\frac{\langle\nabla f(x),x\rangle}{|x|}=\liminf_{r\to\infty}\frac{\langle\nabla f(x),x\rangle}{|x|}\in(0,\infty]\tag8.$$ By $(8)$ we may choose $R\ge d-1$ with $$l:=\inf_{|x|\:\ge\:R}\frac{\langle\nabla f(x),x\rangle}{|x|},$$ $\lambda=l^2/4$ and $c=l/2$ to obtain $$\frac\lambda c+c+\frac{d-1}{|x|}\le l\le\frac{\langle\nabla f(x),x\rangle}{|x|}\;\;\;\text{for all }|x|\ge R\tag9.$$

> This ensures at least that $(3)$ is satisfied for $|x|\ge R$. How do we need to choose $b$ and how do we need to choose $L$ such that $(2)$ is satisfied? (Clearly, with the argumentation above, we would choose $K=\left\{|x|\le R\right\}$.)

Comment: Why does (5) follow from (4)?

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee By definition, $\lambda=\lim_{r\to\infty}\inf_{|x|\ge r}\frac{\langle\nabla f(x),x\rangle}{|x|}$. The only problematic thing could be if $\lambda=\infty$ (for example, when $f(x)=\frac12 x^2+\text{constant}$). Am I missing something?

Comment: Still don't see how (5) follows from the definition of $\lambda$.   Suppose $R \ge r$.  Then $\inf_{|x| \ge R} \nabla f(x) \cdot x / |x| \ge \inf_{|x| \ge r} \nabla f(x) \cdot x / |x|$, since the infimum in the RHS of the inequality is taken over a larger set because $\{ |x| \ge R \} \subseteq \{ |x| \ge r \}$, and so $\lambda \ge \inf_{|x| \ge r} \nabla f(x) \cdot x / |x|$.  This conclusion seems different from (5).

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee By definition of $\lambda$ (assuming $\lambda<\infty$), $$\forall\varepsilon>0:\exists R>0:\forall r\ge R:\left|\lambda-\inf_{|x|\ge r}\frac{\langle\nabla f(x),x\rangle}{|x|}\right|<\varepsilon.$$ And $\lambda\ge\inf_{|x|\ge r}\frac{\langle\nabla f(x),x\rangle}{|x|}$ is trivial for all $r>0$, since $\lambda$ is the supremum of the values on the right-hand side over all $r>0$. As you noted, the right-hand side is increasing in $r$.

Comment: How does (8) follow from (7)?  The sign of the RHS of (8) looks off.  Seems like (7) only implies that $A J / (\lambda J) \le 1$.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee You're right. Don't know what I thought. Please take note of my edit.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee Unfortunately, you've deleted your answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/423691/91890) before I was able to accept it. There were still some issues which prevented me to do so. The essential issue was that I wasn't sure how you justified $\operatorname E[\text{II}\mid\tau_1=s]=\operatorname E[f(Y^1_0)-f(Y^0_s)]1_{\{\:t\:\ge\:s\:\}}$. I've asked for that separateley here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4482416/47771. And the isssue itself is described here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4482321/47771.

Comment: as you know, the bounty on that question was allowed to expire even though I went out of my way to answer the (many) auxiliary questions that came up days before the expiration.  meanwhile you seemed to have vanished.  I'm sorry things couldn't work out, next time I'll be more selective.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee I don't like the fact that the time I can give you the bounty is limited. However, once the issues have been solved, it would be no problem to give you a new bounty-

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee Could you undelete your answer? I will accept it and reward you the bounty. It would be very kind of you if you could do that and additionally explain how you intend to show that $\operatorname E[\text{III}]$ is really $\mathcal O(t^2)$ (you can wait for the bounty, if you like). I'm failing to prove that.

Comment: Done.  I will provide a short explanation for why E[III] = O(t^2) separately and within the next two weeks (really busy right now).

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I thought you said "Could you undelete your answer? I will accept it and reward you the bounty". The bounty has now expired without a reward made.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee I'm sorry. I've immediately started a boundty (worth 100 rep) after I wrote to you. But I couldn't award the bounty before a period of 24 hours. Then I had a bereavement in my family and I forgot the bounty. Now I've started another bounty (worth 200 rep), but I need to wait 24 hours again.

Comment: Sorry to hear about your bereavement.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By $(8)$, $$\langle\nabla f(x),x\rangle\ge\alpha|x|\;\;\;\text{for all }|x|\ge r\tag{10}$$ for some $\alpha>0$ and $r\ge0$. Let $c\in(0,\alpha)$, $\tilde r\ge r$ with $$\tilde r>\frac{d-1}{\alpha-c}\tag{11}$$ and $J\in C^\infty\left(\mathbb R^d\right)$ with $$J(x)=e^{c|x|}\;\;\;\text{for all }|x|\ge\tilde r\tag{12}$$ and $$J(x)\ge1\;\;\;\text{for all }|x|\le\tilde r\tag{13}.$$ Note that $$(LJ)(x)=-c\left(\frac{\langle\nabla f(x),x\rangle}{|x|}-c-\frac{d-1}{|x|}\right)J(x)\le-\underbrace{c\left(\alpha-c-\frac{d-1}{\tilde r}\right)}_{=:\:\lambda\:>\:0}J(x)\tag{14}$$ for all $|x|>\tilde r$. Now, $J$ and $LJ$ are continuous and hence locally bounded (above). Thus, $b_1:=\sup_{|x|\:\le\:\tilde r}J(x)<\infty$ and $b_2:=\sup_{|x|\:\le\:\tilde r}(LJ)(x)<\infty$. Letting $b:=\lambda b_1+b_2$, we obtain $$LJ\le-\lambda J+b1_{\left\{\:|x|\:\le\:\tilde r\:\right\}}\tag{15}.$$

Comment: In deriving a Foster-Lyapunov drift condition, typically $c$ in (4) is not given, but is chosen small enough such that something like (14) holds.  It also seems natural to choose $\alpha = \min(1, \lim_{r \to \infty} \inf_{|x| \ge r x \cdot \nabla f(x)/|x|$.  However, these are minor points, and overall this is nice.