# Construction of a Markov process with prescribed local behavior and state-dependent jump distribution

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, markov-chains

Let

- $(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space
- $\mathcal E_b:=\left\{f:E\to\mathbb R\mid f\text{ is bounded and }\mathcal E\text{-measurable}\right\}$
- $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a Markov semigroup on $(E,\mathcal E)$
- $Q$ denote the weak generator of $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$; i.e. $$\mathcal D(Q):=\left\{f\in\mathcal E_b\mid\forall x\in E:[0,\infty)\ni t\mapsto(\kappa_tf)(x)\text{ is right-differentiable at }0\right\}$$ and $$(Qf)(x):=\left.\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}(\kappa_tf)(x)\right|_{t=0+}\;\;\;\text{for }x\in E\text{ and }f\in\mathcal D(Q)$$
- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $(Y_t)_{t\ge0}$ be an $(E,\mathcal E)$-valued time-homogeneous Markov process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ with transition semigroup $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$
- $\alpha$ be a transition kernel on $(E,\mathcal E)$ and $$Af(x):=\int_E ( f(y)-f(x)) \:\alpha(x,{\rm d}y)\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in E\text{ and }f\in\mathcal D(A):=\mathcal E_b$$

> **Question**: How can we construct an $(E,\mathcal E)$-valued time-homogeneous Markov process $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ with weak generator $$Lf=Qf+Af\;\;\;\text{for all }f\in\mathcal D(L)\subseteq\mathcal D(Q)\cap\mathcal D(A)?\tag1$$

The idea is that the local behavior between jumps of $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ is described by $(Y_t)_{t\ge0}$ and, assuming that $\alpha(x,B)=c(x)\mu(x,B)$ for all $x\in E$ for some $\mathcal E$-measurable $c:E\to[0,\infty)$ and a Markov kernel $\mu$ on $(E,\mathcal E)$, the jumps occur at a state-dependent rate $c$ and are performed according to the state-depedendent distribution $\mu$.

The process should be described by something like $$X_t=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N_0}1_{[\tau_n,\:\tau_{n+1})}(t)Y^{(n)}_{t-\tau_n}\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0\tag1,$$ where $\tau_n$ is the time of the $n$th-jump and the $Y^{(n)}$ are independent copies of $Y$.

> However, how do we need to define the $\tau_n$ precisely and how do we see that the weak generator of $(1)$ is actually equal to $L$?

I'm aware of the following simpler result: If $(W_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ is a time-homogeneous Markov chain on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ with transition kernel $\kappa$ and $(N_t)_{t\ge0}$ is a Poisson process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ with intensity $r>0$ and $W$ is independent of $N$, then $$Z_t:=W_{N_t}\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0$$ is a time-homogeneous Markov process with transition semigroup $\left(e^{t(\kappa-r)}\right)_{t\ge0}$ and generator $r\left(\kappa-\operatorname{id}_{\mathcal E_b}\right)$.

In particular, if $W$ is a random walk with step distribution $\alpha^{-1}\nu$; i.e. $W_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\xi_i$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ for some independent identically $\alpha^{-1}\nu$-distributed process $(Z_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$, then the generator of $Z$ is given by $$\mathcal E_b\ni g\mapsto\int g(\;\cdot\;+y)-g\:\nu({\rm d}y).$$

Maybe a similar construction and hence an expression different from $(1)$ from which it is easier to derive the desired result is possible in the setting of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construction given by the OP is almost correct. Here is a slight correction: $$
X_t = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 1_{[\tau_n,\tau_{n+1})}(t) Y_{t - \tau_n}^{n} \;, \tag{1}
$$ where we have introduced

- $\{\tau_i\}$ are a sequence of jump times defined via $\tau_{i+1}=\tau_i+\xi_i$, $\tau_0=0$, and $\{\xi_i \} \overset{i.i.d.}{\sim} \operatorname{Exp}(1)$ ; and,
- $\{Y^{i}\}$ are independent realizations of $Y$ with $Y_0^i=x$ if $i=0$ and else sample $Y_0^i \mid (Y^0, \dots, Y^{i-1}, \xi_0, \dots, \xi_i) \sim \alpha(Y_{\tau_i - \tau_{i-1}}^{i-1}, \cdot)$ .

In other words,
$$
X_t = \begin{cases}
Y^0_t & t < \tau_1 \;,  \\
Y^1_{t-\tau_1} & \tau_1 \le t < \tau_2 \;,  \\
Y^2_{t-\tau_2} & \tau_2 \le t < \tau_3 \;,  \\
\vdots
\end{cases}
$$

To see that the weak generator of (1) is indeed $L=Q+A$, write $f (X_t)  - f(x) = \rm{I} + \rm{II} + \rm{III}$  where \begin{align*}
\rm{I} &:= (f(X_t) - f(x)) 1_{\{t < \tau_1 \}} \;, \\
\rm{II} &:= (f(Y_0^1) - f(Y_{\tau_1}^0)) 1_{\{t \ge \tau_1 \}} \;,  \\
\rm{III} &:= (f(Y_{\tau_1}^0) - f(x) + f(X_t) - f(Y_0^1))  1_{\{t \ge \tau_1 \}} \;.
\end{align*}
Then \begin{align*}
E[\rm{I}] &= e^{-t} ( \kappa_t f(x) - f(x) ) = e^{-t} E \int_0^t Qf (Y_s^0) ds \;, \\
E[{\rm II} \mid \tau_1 = s] &= E[f(Y_0^1) - f(Y_{s}^0)] 1_{\{ t \ge s \}} = E[ A f(Y_s^0) ] 1_{\{ t \ge s \}} \;, \\
E[ \rm{II} ] &= E \int_0^{\infty} E[ {\rm II} \mid \tau_1 = s] e^{-s} ds = E \int_0^t e^{-s} A f(Y_s^0) ds \;.
\end{align*} One can similarly show that $E( \rm{III} )$ is $O(t^2)$ for $t \in [0,1]$.  Therefore, combining the above and using $(e^{-s} - e^{-t}) \le (t-s)$ for $t \ge s$, one obtains that for all $ t \in [0,1]$ $$
E[f(X_t)] - f(x) = E\int_0^t (A f(Y_s^0) + Q f(Y_s^0)) ds + O(t^2) \;.
$$
While this construction/analysis covers the case of constant jump rates, the case of state-dependent jump rates can be treated similarly as discussed in the comments below.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please clarify what you mean when you say that "$\{Y^i\}$ are independent realizations of $Y$ with $Y_0=x$". With respect to which probability measure are the $Y^i$ independent and what is $x$? Do you intend to introduce a family $\operatorname P_x$ of probability measures such that $\{Y^i:i\in\mathbb N_0\}$ is $\operatorname P_x$-indepndent, $\operatorname P[Y^0_0=x]=1$ and the distribution of $Y^i$ under $\operatorname P_x$ is $\alpha(Y_{\tau_i - \tau_{i-1}}^{i-1}, \cdot)$ for all $x\in E$?

Comment: Yes, except that I think you meant to say  "the distribution of $Y^i_0$ under $P_x$ is $\alpha(Y^{i-1}_{\tau_i - \tau_{I-1}}, \cdot)$".

Comment: Yes, sorry, that's what I've meant. It also seems like that we need some kind of independence between $Y^i$ and $\tau_{i-1}$, since I don't understand how you obtain $E[\rm{I}] = e^{-t} ( \kappa_t f(x) - f(x) ) $ without that.

Comment: BTW, the more general concatenation of Markov processes we have talked about in the other thread is also described in the following paper: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwi-j9WCm5n4AhVvSfEDHVE9A0MQFnoECAIQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmadoc.bib.uni-mannheim.de%2F41517%2F1%2FDissertation_Florian_Werner.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3nuWn2oH0DTuqalEiR-3mW. It starts in Chapter 11 on p. 55. I'm not 100% sure, but the scenario considered here should be the special case described in chapter 13.1.

Comment: The "transfer kernel" should be our $\alpha$, if I'm not missing something. However, I really struggle to understand why the rather complicated construction described in chapter 11.3 is necessary. If all $X^i$ are the same, doesn't this construction somehow mimic the construction in the proof of the Ionescu-Tulcea theorem from which we can infer the existence of independent processes? If you know something about this stuff, it would be great to hear what you can say.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I will consider the independence thing later. Note that is is chapter 11.1 (not 11.3) which is about the "concatenation of two processe". Chapter 11.3 is about the "concatenation of countably many processes". (a) Isn't the construction in Chapter 11.3 precisely the same as you gave in your answer? (b) If we define your $X_t$ in the same manner as it is done in chapter 11.1; i.e. $X_t=Y^1_t$ if $t<\tau_1$ and $X_t=Y^2_{t-\tau_1}$ if $\ge\tau_1$, shouldn't the resulting process still have the same generator?

Comment: (c) Hm, the paper you've linked to in an other post (https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.05037) is claiming that the process is the one described in section 11.1 ... What are we missing? (d) How do you obtain that $Y^i$ (the whole process) is $\operatorname P_x$-independent from $\xi$ for all $x\ni E$? It must stem from your assumption $Y^i_0 \sim \alpha(Y_{\tau_i - \tau_{i-1}}^{i-1}, \cdot)$ under $\operatorname P_x$ for all $x\in E$ and $i\in\mathbb N$. What precisely do you mean by this claim on the distribution? Does it mean

Comment: $\operatorname P_x\left[Y^i_0\in B\mid Y_{\tau_i - \tau_{i-1}}^{i-1}\right]=\alpha(Y_{\tau_i - \tau_{i-1}}^{i-1},B)$ for all $x\in E$ and $B\in\mathcal E$? So, for example, $\operatorname P_x\left[Y^1_0\in B\mid Y^0_{\xi_1}\right]=\alpha(Y^0_{\xi_1},B)$ for all $x\in E$ and $B\in\mathcal E$. From this not even $Y^1_0$ should be independent from $\xi_1$ ... So, maybe you've meant that $Y^i$ is $\operatorname P_x$ independent from $\xi_{i-1}$ instead. However, I only see that $Y^i_0$ and $\xi_i$ are .$\operatorname P_x$.

Comment: (c) a key difference between the setup here and the one in https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.05037, is that here the jump distribution depends on the current state of the process whereas there it does not, but otherwise, the two constructions look the same.  I’m not so confident about the thesis you shared.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. Could you clarify what $Y^i_0 \sim \alpha(Y_{\tau_i - \tau_{i-1}}^{i-1}, \cdot)$ precisely means?

Comment: The law of $Y_0^i$ is $\alpha(Y_{\tau_i-\tau_{i-1}}^{i-1},\cdot)$.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't (immediately) make sense. The law of $Y_0^i$ is a probability measure on $(E,\mathcal E)$ whereas $\alpha(Y_{\tau_i-\tau_{i-1}}^{i-1},\cdot)$ is a Markov kernel with source $(\Omega,\sigma(Y_{\tau_i-\tau_{i-1}}^{i-1}))$ and target $(E,\mathcal E)$.

Comment: Yes, I’m being a bit lazy:  what I mean is that $Law(Y_0^i)(dy)=\alpha(Y_{\tau_i-\tau_{i-1}}^{i-1},dy)$. In other words $P[Y_0^i \in B] = \int_B \alpha(Y_{\tau_i-\tau_{i-1}}^{i-1}, dy)$ — exactly as you wrote above in one of your questions.

Comment: I know that you're an experienced researcher and so I guess I'm just unfamiliar with your notation, but what is the expression on the right-hand side of $P[Y_0^i \in B] = \int_B \alpha(Y_{\tau_i-\tau_{i-1}}^{i-1}, dy)$? There is still a dependence on $\omega\in\Omega$ and if you integrate with respect to the second variable, your integral should simply be $\alpha(Y^{i-1}_{\tau_i-\tau_{i-1}},B)$.

Comment: Don't you mean $\operatorname P_x\left[Y^i_0\in B\mid Y_{\tau_i - \tau_{i-1}}^{i-1}\right]=\alpha(Y_{\tau_i - \tau_{i-1}}^{i-1},B)$ as I suggested before?

Comment: Exactly, that is what i meant, and you indeed wrote it correctly/better by conditioning on the pre jump state of the process.

Comment: Okay, we are getting closer. First of all, note that we need that $(Y_t)_{t\ge0}$ is $(\mathcal F^Y_t)_{t\ge0}$-progressive in order to ensure that $Y_\tau$ is $\mathcal F^Y_\tau$-measurable for every $(\mathcal F^Y_t)_{t\ge0}$-stopping time $\tau$. Now I guess we need to assume that $\tau_i$ is an $(\mathcal F^{Y^{i-1}}_t)_{t\ge0}$-stopping time. However, for example, $\text P_x[Y^1_0\in B\mid Y^0_{\tau_1}]=\alpha(Y^0_{\tau_1},B)$ for all $(x,B)∈E×\mathcal E$. Since the right-hand side is clearly *not* independent of $τ_1$, I don't get how you infer independence of $Y^1_0$ and $τ_1=\xi_0$ ...

Comment: Please note that I only said that $Y^0_t$ is independent of $\tau_1$, which is all that is needed to prove $E[I]=…$.

Comment: For some reason, I've tried to prove independence of $Y^1_t$ from $\tau_1$ which is clearly not what you wrote ... Howerver, from what are you infering the independence of $Y^0_t$ and $\xi_0$? We only that $\xi_0$ is independent from $\xi_1,\xi_2,\ldots$ and $\mathcal L_x(Y^0_t)=\mathcal L_x(Y^0_0)\kappa^0_t$, where $\mathcal L_x(Y^0_t)$ is the distribution of $Y^0_t$ under $\operatorname P_x$ and $(\kappa^0_t)_{t\ge0}$ is the transition semigroup of $Y^0$. Now $\mathcal L_x(Y^0_0)=\delta_x$ ...

Comment: The inference is based on an assumption which really should be made explicit

Comment: Which assumption is this?

Comment: The claim that $Y_t^0$ and $\xi_0$ are independent is an assumption.

Comment: Well, okay, then it's hard to prove it :) However, I think this assumption is rather strong. In the paper $\tau_1=\inf\left\{t\ge0:\int_0^t\kappa(Y^0_s)\:{\rm d}s\ge\xi_0\right\}$ for some bounded $\mathcal E$-measurable $\kappa:E\to[0,\infty)$ and $\xi_0\sim\operatorname{Exp}(1)$ independent of $Y^0$. With this, $\tau_1$ is clearly not independent of $Y^0$. Can the claim still be proved?

Comment: It is a strong assumption in the proof and I don’t know how to relax it, but it does work for some important special cases, including the time homogeneous cases (your original question) and time inhomogeneous piecewise deterministic Markov processes.

Comment: I think we need to impose a different assumption. Instead of $\operatorname P_x\left[Y^1_0\in B\mid Y^0_{\tau_1}\right]=\alpha\left(Y^0_{\tau_1},B\right)$, we should need to impose the stronger assumption $\operatorname P_x\left[Y^1_0\in B\mid \mathcal F^{Y^0}_{\tau_1}\right]=\alpha\left(Y^0_{\tau_1},B\right)$ for all $(x,B)\in E\times\mathcal E$. With this assumption, we immediately obtain $\operatorname E_x\left[\int_0^t(Af)(Y^0_s)\:{\rm d}s\right]$ for all $x\in E$ without the need of assuming $\operatorname P_x$-independence of $Y^0$ and $\tau_1$.

Comment: As I wrote before, I'm mainly interested in the setting described in the paper and the $\tau_i$ defined therein. In that scenario, $Y^0$ is **not** independent of $\xi_0$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke: what you are asking about in the original question is a homogeneous MP with state-independent jump rates: I think the proof that is given applies to this case.  However, what it seems you are interested in is the case of state-dependent jump rates.  Both cases are not time-inhomogeneous MPs.  In the case of state-dependent jump rates, a similar result does indeed hold, except $E[I] = E[ (f(Y^0_t) - f(x)) \exp(-\int_0^t \kappa(Y^0_s) ds)]$ and the additional factor contributes at only $O(t^2)$ provided that $\kappa$ is sufficiently regular, e.g. bounded.

Comment: I intended to write "we immediately obtain $\operatorname E[\text I]=\operatorname E_x\left[\int_0^t(Af)(Y^0_s)\:{\rm d}s\right]$ for all $x\in E$" in my comment above. Do you agree that we should impose the assumption $\operatorname P_x\left[Y^1_0\in B\mid \mathcal F^{Y^0}_{\tau_1}\right]=\alpha\left(Y^0_{\tau_1},B\right)$ for all $(x,B)\in E\times\mathcal E$ instead of the one you imposed before?

Comment: I think you are referring to $E[{\rm II}]$.  To avoid confusion, maybe $P_x[X_{\tau_1} \in B \mid (X_t)_{0 \le t < \tau_1} ] = P_x[Y_0^1 \in B \mid Y^0_{\tau_1}] = \alpha(Y^0_{\tau_1}, B) = \alpha(X_{\tau_1-},B)$.  In any case, I see no reason why the proof given in this answer does not work in the general homogeneous case with state-dependent jump rates, under suitable conditions on the jump rates.

Comment: Do you think you can edit the question and add how we can show $E(III)=O(t^2)$ soon? BTW, am I missing something, or does $$\tilde X_t:=\begin{cases}Y^0_t&\text{, if }t<\tau_1\\Y^1_{t-\tau_1}&\text{, if }\tau_1\le t\end{cases}$$ admit the same generator $X_t$?

Comment: Certainly.  Have not forgotten about this.  This week is difficult because I have quite a few reports due, but I'll try to add it asap.  Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Write $III = III_1 + III_2 + III_3$ where $III_1 = (f (Y^0_{\tau_1}) - f(x)) 1_{t \ge \tau_1}$, $III_2 = (f(X_t) - f(Y_0^1)) 1_{ \tau_1 \le t \le \tau_2}$ and $III_3 =  (f(X_t) - f(Y_0^1)) 1_{ t > \tau_2}$.  Then $E[III_1] = E[ \int_0^{\tau_1} Q f(Y^0_s) ds ; t \ge \tau_1] \le t \| Q f \| (1-e^{-t}) = O(t^2)$, $E[III_2] = E[ \int_{\tau_1}^t Q f(Y_{s-\tau_1}^1) ds ; \tau_1 \le t < \tau_2] \le t^2 e^{-t} \| Q f \| = O(t^2)$    $E[III_3] \le \| f\| P( t \ge \tau_2) \le \| f \| (1-e^{-t} -t e^{-t}) = O(t^2)$.  Hope that clarifies.